# How to get hemisphere using google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry, geocoding, computational-geometry, google-maps-api-2

I'm using google map api V3 to set map and to do such mapping related functions. Now I want to know about hemisphere of current location that on which side it is from particular location and need to set marker image accordingly.

I searched about particular function or trick to get hemisphere using google map api but I couldn't get it. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: No that I can get. I want to know the hemisphere of the current location from the particular location whether it is on south side or north side.

Comment: yeah, if you want north or south hemisphere, just examine the latitude and see if it is positive or negative (on google maps they run from -90 to +90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if latitude is < 0 then coordinate is located on the southern hemisphere, otherwise on the North hemisphere.